# ssl socket write gives connection reset exception

Tags: sockets, ssl, javapns

I am trying to send ios push notification using javapns library . the code is working fine on java 6 but not working on java 7 . I am trying to write on a ssl socket by java code 
  this.socket.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
but getting following exception : -

> 2015-09-24 02:01:17,330 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST
>   mode] ERROR javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager
>   (PushNotificationManager.java:496) - Delivery error
>       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
>         at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:464)
>   [utils-1.0.jar:?]
>         at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:409)
>   [utils-1.0.jar:?]
>         at javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.runList(NotificationThread.java:283)
>   [utils-1.0.jar:?]
>         at javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.run(NotificationThread.java:254)
>   [utils-1.0.jar:?]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]

Following are my ssl debug log : -

```
*** Certificate chain

chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: ........
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22222491044564264786925450301128660800404037455402211937155693765439451266775814064935111308236503917661658380453607223444671197507922227372310694498331784203397249559620562506847738658137494429967865235154139927237328515659798669693649542833648664525838898423359833650942229563615420055801398510282090750116916759108752545159033267269553610447830532132801594757535863574777003658295660123855620269370519852284530709335738820289388013418673721050782042119531816409879900413319632795054390149130447840278225455201462347192736907867086706041266601675705875530393925455170420669674672723643704537136254104782678046353641
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Jul 16 12:10:32 IST 2015,
               To: Fri Jul 15 12:10:32 IST 2016]
  Issuer: CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations, O=Apple Inc., C=US
  SerialNumber: [    25dea3f4 f4f072b3]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: 1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2 Criticality=true
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 02 05 00                                        ....


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.apple.com/ocsp03-wwdr01
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 88 27 17 09 A9 B6 18 60   8B EC EB BA F6 47 59 C5  .'.....`.....GY.
0010: 52 54 A3 B7                                        RT..
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113635.100.5.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.2
  qualifier: 0000: 30 81 B6 0C 81 B3 52 65   6C 69 61 6E 63 65 20 6F  0.....Reliance o
0010: 6E 20 74 68 69 73 20 63   65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61  n this certifica
0020: 74 65 20 62 79 20 61 6E   79 20 70 61 72 74 79 20  te by any party 
0030: 61 73 73 75 6D 65 73 20   61 63 63 65 70 74 61 6E  assumes acceptan
0040: 63 65 20 6F 66 20 74 68   65 20 74 68 65 6E 20 61  ce of the then a
0050: 70 70 6C 69 63 61 62 6C   65 20 73 74 61 6E 64 61  pplicable standa
0060: 72 64 20 74 65 72 6D 73   20 61 6E 64 20 63 6F 6E  rd terms and con
0070: 64 69 74 69 6F 6E 73 20   6F 66 20 75 73 65 2C 20  ditions of use, 
0080: 63 65 72 74 69 66 69 63   61 74 65 20 70 6F 6C 69  certificate poli
0090: 63 79 20 61 6E 64 20 63   65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61  cy and certifica
00A0: 74 69 6F 6E 20 70 72 61   63 74 69 63 65 20 73 74  tion practice st
00B0: 61 74 65 6D 65 6E 74 73   2E                       atements.

], PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 2A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 77 77 77 2E 61 70 70  .*http://www.app
0010: 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 63   65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61  le.com/certifica
0020: 74 65 61 75 74 68 6F 72   69 74 79 2F              teauthority/

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=true
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  codeSigning
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 6F FB BD 5A 59 70 1C 2E   77 32 9A 97 69 C3 23 0E  o..ZYp..w2..i.#.
0010: EF D8 E9 D0                                        ....
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 90 BE B9 5B E7 66 C1 B4   C1 C8 60 90 69 5F 01 04  ...[.f....`.i_..
0010: 2B C4 E6 9E 8D 13 8C A7   3F 81 55 6C CD D1 47 48  +.......?.Ul..GH
0020: 3C D7 D8 3E F5 C2 69 A7   A2 21 CE 15 08 F7 D9 8C  <..>..i..!......
0030: 2D FE 37 29 AD DC E3 CA   27 27 83 2C 15 95 4D 40  -.7)....''.,..M@
0040: EA 2C AD EF 99 7C 9B 84   59 3F 6C E6 BA 07 F4 EC  .,......Y?l.....
0050: 05 36 E4 58 EA B0 DF 00   AB 54 F2 FF 6B AE C2 C1  .6.X.....T..k...
0060: E4 3C D3 23 79 61 D1 67   DD 0C 0D 2B 77 E0 8E 6F  .<.#ya.g...+w..o
0070: A2 7B 21 13 D2 4F D7 8B   98 A7 E0 22 E9 95 D7 1A  ..!..O....."....
0080: C5 71 0A 15 35 77 38 37   EC F9 CC 60 79 2D A5 E0  .q..5w87...`y-..
0090: DA C2 78 AD 59 88 7B 92   93 66 9A 44 F7 58 8C 0D  ..x.Y....f.D.X..
00A0: 28 E3 42 D0 79 DC F5 23   C7 36 D0 61 0A 34 61 F3  (.B.y..#.6.a.4a.
00B0: 16 AE 7B D8 8B BC B8 6B   D6 05 C4 E4 EF B0 BF 4B  .......k.......K
00C0: 66 E1 6F 59 EC 67 F6 A3   C0 49 7A 83 8A 7B FC 7B  f.oY.g...Iz.....
00D0: 26 3C 42 16 F7 DE DB 74   4D 1A A5 7F AE C2 36 C4  &<B....tM.....6.
00E0: 8E 5A F9 75 05 3A A5 13   70 0C 69 96 00 CB FD 77  .Z.u.:..p.i....w
00F0: 4A 9E C8 E4 AA 39 75 7D   6D C9 79 04 BC DF 59 EF  J....9u.m.y...Y.

]
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1729
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 00 2E C1 C7 9F 24   B2 E9 02 59 7B D2 8A A7  .......$...Y....
0010: 22 D3 72 B2 16 55 5F 5C   E1 30 7D 4A 56 F1 3C 32  ".r..U_\.0.JV.<2
0020: 5D 77 8F 13 BD B0 E9 6A   84 9E 81 0D 0B 38 D5 0E  ]w.....j.....8..
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 56 03 10 94 63 A2 8C A1   6D 75 2F F0 38 EC CD 4F  V...c...mu/.8..O
0010: 3A D6 46 C7 C4 2D 5F 76   4B 38 3F FC 28 59 6B 04  :.F..-_vK8?.(Yk.
Server Nonce:
0000: B2 1F 50 60 42 F5 94 7A   5B 7C FE 50 60 3E 84 BC  ..P`B..z[..P`>..
0010: CB 18 B7 B1 E8 50 56 6E   F9 DD 6E E2 B9 34 25 01  .....PVn..n..4%.
Master Secret:
0000: 03 87 6A 7D 0E 69 76 FA   5F 2E 48 BB B7 77 79 0F  ..j..iv._.H..wy.
0010: 5E 59 CF 32 BA B5 D7 2E   0F 9D 43 F2 4F F1 CD 52  ^Y.2......C.O..R
0020: DF A7 05 EB 47 BF FD 18   48 F0 DD F1 78 10 47 FF  ....G...H...x.G.
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: ED B5 4A 85 1D CC 96 D2   D0 94 29 40 AE 8F C3 10  ..J.......)@....
0010: 74 52 24 8D                                        tR$.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: B9 ED CD B7 30 52 1F 74   9E 47 71 41 2A 1B 90 C7  ....0R.t.GqA*...
0010: AF 2F 93 4E                                        ./.N
Client write key:
0000: A0 B0 7C 23 2F C7 A3 5D   24 03 B4 1F F9 2B B2 97  ...#/..]$....+..
Server write key:
0000: 29 4C 64 FB 39 02 96 43   7A 5B F5 1D D4 2A 51 B7  )Ld.9..Cz[...*Q.
Client write IV:
0000: 85 3C C4 38 B4 9F 41 92   B6 88 7A 47 F6 B9 82 C1  .<.8..A...zG....
Server write IV:
0000: FA 04 7C A8 D7 29 A3 0D   5F 20 BF 3C 4C C8 52 9A  .....).._ .<L.R.
*** CertificateVerify
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 221, 26, 21, 239, 125, 223, 149, 73, 149, 170, 46, 218 }
***
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, called closeSocket()
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, called close()
JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode, called closeInternal(true)


abhishek$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
abhishek$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

abhishek$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Edit : When I printed this SSLSession

```
    SSLSession session = socket.getSession();
//I got [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
```

// Returns the SSL Session in use by this connection. These can be long lived, and frequently correspond to an entire login session for some user. The session specifies a particular cipher suite which is being actively used by all connections in that session, as well as the identities of the session's client and server.
This method will initiate the initial handshake if necessary and then block until the handshake has been established.
If an error occurs during the initial handshake, this method returns an invalid session object which reports an invalid cipher suite of "SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL".

System.out.println(session.getLocalCertificates());
    // I got null
    While Using same certificates in java 6 I did not get null .

Comment: If handshaking fails, the "invalid" session probably is a dummy object that doesn't contain the local cert(s) even though you have a keystore, probably because a keystore can contain multiple credentials and without going through the selection and validation process of a handshake JSSE can't know which is the "right" one.

Answer (score 0):

The peer has closed the connection. You would have to look at its logs to see why. Possibly it asked you for a certificate and you didn't provide one.

Comment: I have created a certificate (a p12 file ) . the certificate is fine as I am able to use the same certificate on java 6 . the problem appeared when I upgraded my java to 7 .  i have also upgraded openssl .  openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

Comment: EJP , I have modified my questions . My question is why the same certificate is not working on java 7.

Comment: Although incomplete the log clearly shows sending a client cert. This cert might be *unacceptable* but if so the server response should be a specific alert not RST. I agree server-side details would be best, but my understanding is (all) Apple-push servers are run by Apple who may not give this info. @abhishek Log shows client cert without the chain cert apparently used per Apple website (or even caIss for it) as required, and has ExtendedKeyUsage for codesigning but not clientauth as required. But if this is an Apple-run server it can trust Apple chains and practices another server wouldn't.

Comment: ... I understand Apple has test servers; have you tried those or can you, with what results? Also, why do you mention OpenSSL? You clearly aren't using it in your client, are you actually running an OpenSSL server rather than the Apple one? Do you want to use OpenSSL as a test client? Java7 versus 6 client SSL does optionally support TLS1.1 and 1.2, but from the log that wasn't used here; supports ECC suites, but that was dealt with earlier in the protocol (Hello); and supports SNI for URLConnection, but your code isn't using that. I don't see anything else obvious.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It isn't clear from the log whether that certificate chain is being sent or received. The client isn't permitted to send a certificate that isn't trusted by one of the signers in the CertificateRequest message: that would be an SSL API bug. There is no alert defined for a client certificate that isn't acceptable (expired, subjectDN not authorized, etc.). The server's only recourse is to close the connection.